# How to reverse the byte order of an 8-byte string in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I change FF02500000000020 to 20000000005002FF in Perl?

The way I can do is:

1. separate FF02500000000020 to two parts FF025000 and 00000020
2. add 0x before them;
3. then

   ```
   my $num2=0xFF025000;  
   my $num3=0x00000020;  
   my $s2=pack('I!',$num2);  
   my $s3=pack('I!',$num3);  
   print unpack ("H*", "$s2") . "\n";  
   print unpack ("H*", "$s3") . "\n";
   ```
4. then combine the two parts again.

Is there any simple way?

Comment: What input data are you starting with?  A string of raw bytes?  A string in hexadecimal format?

Comment: This is another thing I was confused. it is the variable I got from another string \xff\x02\x50\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20 using  @array= split(/\\x/, $data); and use spice and join to get this variable. and I can apply function hex to this variable. I guess it is string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print reverse split /(..)/, 'FF02500000000020';
```

Or, if you'd like it in a scalar:

```
$val = join '', reverse split /(..)/, 'FF02500000000020';
```

Comment: Hi, what is the difference between this:

Comment: my $hex_pers_flags_endian =  "FF02500000000020";
        my $hex_pers_flags = reverse split /(..)/, $hex_pers_flags_endian;
        print "hex_pers_flags = $hex_pers_flags\n";
        print reverse split /(..)/, $hex_pers_flags_endian;

Comment: if print reverse dirrectly how the right answer, if store the result in $hex_pers_flags and then print it, show  02000000000520FF

Comment: I know the reason. should be: my $hex_pers_flags_endian =  "FF02500000000020";
        my @hex_pers_flags = reverse split /(..)/, $hex_pers_flags_endian;
         my $hex_pers_flags = join '', @hex_pers_flags;

Comment: the result of split is array should be change back to string

Comment: So: `my $res = join '', reverse split /(..)/, $data;`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
$str = unpack 'H*', reverse pack 'H*', $str;
```

Note, this will lowercase the hex characters so you may want to add `uc()` at the start if preserving the case is important:

```
$str = uc unpack 'H*', reverse pack 'H*', $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert::Binary::C. Looks like it might do what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the person wanted, but it is nice to know that it exists.

Comment: It's probably a better solution for storing things in a particular byte order, assuming that is why the OP is asking their particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data into a (single) variable - call it `$data`.Then use (scalar) [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html).

```
print scalar reverse $data;
```

Or:

```
my $reversed = reverse $data;
```

Comment: not corret, it will revert to 02000000000520FF, I want 20000000005002FF

Comment: It depends on the data type that you want to handle.  It reverse the bytes; if you use a string containing hex, then you don't get the result.  If you have binary data, it would work.  If in fact you have a string and want to reverse pairs of bytes, then you split the string into a list of pairs of bytes, reverse the order of the list, and reassemble - as in one of the other answers.  But imprecise questions beget imprecise answers.  If you had shown an example, 'given `my $data = qq{...};`, how do I get the result `my $res = qq{...};`?', then everyone would have known what you wanted.

Comment: ic, so The answer I post is misleading. In fact the input is a string $hex_pers_flags_endian = "FF02500000000020", not a hex number -0xFF025000...., so they are diffferent. Thanks