# need a shell script to convert big endian to little endian

Tags: bash, shell, endianness

I need a shell script program to print the hexadecimal number from big endian to little endian

#### For example

- Input: `my virtual address = 00d66d7e`
- Output: `7e6dd600`

How can I can I create this in a bash script?

Comment: looks like simple string manipulation.

Comment: Why don't show what you have tried? Stackoverflow is not for request. It is for answering questions

Comment: Also, what does C relate to the shell? And what shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command-line to reverse byte order/change endianess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438099/command-line-tool-to-reverse-byte-order-change-endianess). Also see [How to reverse the byte order of an 8-byte string in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4370219).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For 32 bit addresses, assuming it's zero padded:

```
v=00d66d7e 
echo ${v:6:2}${v:4:2}${v:2:2}${v:0:2}
# 7e6dd600
```

Answer (score 17):

Just had to do this... but from decimal to little endian.. adapting that here:

```
echo 00d66d7e | tac -rs .. | echo "$(tr -d '\n')"
```

achieves the desired result, for arbitrarily sized hexadecimal representations of unsigned integers.

(h/t 'tac -rs' MestreLion, very nice!)

Comment: *very* clever solution, +1! May I suggest an improvement? `tac`, or at least GNU `tac`, accepts a regex as separator, so grep is not needed: 
`echo "AABBCC" | tac -rs ..`

Comment: note, the unusual echo "$()" mechanism it basically just to get a newline at the end... could replace with { tr -d '\n'; echo; } or some such.

Comment: Very nice solution. I'd prefer `echo -n 00d66d7e | tac -rs .. ; echo` but that's just taste I guess.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Karoly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296839/need-a-shell-script-to-convert-big-endian-to-little-endian#22297123) you could use the following script, reading an argument or piped input:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check 1st arg or stdin
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    exit
  else
    v=`cat /dev/stdin`
  fi
else
  v=$1
fi

i=${#v}

while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
    i=$[$i-2]
    echo -n ${v:$i:2}
done

echo
```

For e.g. you could save this script as endian.sh and make it executable with:

```
chmod u+x endian.sh
```

Then:

```
echo 00d66d7e | ./endian.sh
```

gives you:

```
7e6dd600
```

For a different length string:

```
echo d76f411475428afc90947ee320 | ./endian.sh
```

result would be:

```
20e37e9490fc8a427514416fd7
```

**#Update:** Modified the script to accept the input either as an argument or from stdin, addressing [Freewind's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296839/need-a-shell-script-to-convert-big-endian-to-little-endian#comment94477319_34327002). So now:

```
./endian.sh d76f411475428afc90947ee320
```

also works and gives you:

```
20e37e9490fc8a427514416fd7
```

Comment: How to change the script to make it work with `./endian.sh d76f411475428afc90947ee320`? Thanks!

Comment: @Freewind [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55731305/409958) addresses your request

Comment: Modified the script to make it work with an argument as well. @Freewind

Answer (score 3):

This works for dash (and many other shells) :

```
v=0x12345678
v2=$(( (v<<8 & 0xff00ff00) | (v>>8 & 0xff00ff) ))
v2=$(( (v2<<16 & 0xffff0000) | v2>>16 ))
printf '0x%08x\n' $v2
```

Result should be "0x78563412"

```
${v:6:2} is for bash.
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to Freewind's comment request and building off of [hutheano's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327002/409958), I wrote my own bash script and I include a condensed version below. The full script can be downloaded [here](http://github.com/NoodleOfDeath/be2le/blob/master/be2le).

**The following implementation accounts for odd length strings, `0x` or `\x` prefixes, and multiple output formats** and can be used like the following:

```
$ be2le d76f411475428afc90947ee320 0xaaff 0xffa '\x3'
20e37e9490fc8a427514416fd7
0xffaa
0xfa0f
\x03
```

**[be2le](http://github.com/NoodleOfDeath/be2le/blob/master/be2le) bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

args=()

format=preserve
delimiter="\n"
nonewline=false
join=false
strip=false

while (( "$#" )); do
    case "$1" in
        -h|--help) usage;;
        -f) format=$2; shift 2;;
        --format=*) format="${1#*=}"; shift;;
        -d) delimiter=$2; shift 2;;
        --delimiter=*) delimiter="${1#*=}"; shift;;
        -n|--no-newline) nonewline=true; shift;;
        -j|--join) join=true; shift;;
        -s|--strip-null) strip=true; shift;;
        -*|--*) echo "Error: unsupported flag $1 specified"; exit 1;;
        *) args=( "${args[@]}" "$1" ); shift;;
    esac
done

case "$format" in
    preserve);;
    int) prefix="0x";;
    char) prefix="\x";; 
    raw) ;;
    *) echo "Error: unsupported format $format"; exit 1;;
esac

n=0
parts=()
for arg in ${args[@]}; do

    digest=""
    prefix=""

    # remove prefix if string begins with "0x"
    if [[ $arg =~ ^[0\\]x ]]; then
        if [ "$format" == "preserve" ]; then
            prefix=${arg:0:2}
        fi
        arg=${arg:2}
    fi

    # zero-pad if string has odd length
    if [ $[${#arg} % 2] != 0 ]; then
        arg="0$arg"
    fi

    part=""
    i=${#arg}
    while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
        i=$[$i-2]
        byte=${arg:$i:2}
        if [ $strip == true ] && [ -z "$part" ] && [ $byte == "00" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        case "$format" in
            int) part="$part"'0x'"$byte ";;
            char) part="$part\x$byte";;
            raw) part="$part$(printf "%b" "\x$byte")";;
            *) part="$part$byte";;
        esac
    done

    digest="$prefix$digest$part"

    parts=( "${parts[@]}" "$digest" )
    n=$[$n+1]

done

if [ $join == true ]; then
    case "$format" in
        *) printf "%s" "${parts[@]}";;
    esac
else
    i=0
    for part in "${parts[@]}"; do
        if [[ $(($i + 1)) < $n ]]; then
            printf "%s$delimiter" "$part"
        else
            printf "%s" "$part"
        fi
        i=$(($i+1))
    done
fi

if [ $nonewline == false ]; then
    echo
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is for flipping 16 bit data.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]; then exit; fi

data=`cat /dev/stdin | od -An -vtx1 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n'`
length=${#data}

i=0
while [ $i -lt $length ]; do
    echo -n -e "\x${data:$[$i+2]:2}"
    echo -n -e "\x${data:$[$i]:2}"
    i=$[$i+4]
done
```